# English name translation of “Jerron” into chinese

Tags: translation

I am looking for a translation for 'Jerron' to chinese. Simplified please. Already tried Google and just would like to double check. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Foreign names are customarily not translated but transliterated into Chinese.

It is extremely rare to use a straight translation even when the foreign name is a common noun.

We do not translate the name 'Mr. Stone' to '石先生'. The name 'Stone' is transliterated to '斯通' /sī tōng/

We do not translate the name 'Mr. White' to '白先生', The name 'White' is transliterated to '怀特' /huái tè/

One thing about transliteration is there are many homophones in Chinese, not to mention each of them also has dozens of similar-sounding characters. Therefore the same English name can be transliterated in many different ways using different characters.

For example, Nixon is currently transliterated to 尼克松 /níkèsōng/ or 尼克森/ níkè sēn/ in Chinese, but some transliterated it to 尼克虫 /níkè chóng/ before he visited China and improved the relationship between China and The United States -- ( 松 = pine; 森 = forest; 虫 = worm)

> Google Translate result for 'Jerron' is '杰伦' /jié lún/ and it is acceptable.

> 杰伦 can easily be a real Chinese first name

*Note: It is also a common practice for foreigners not using a transliteration of their own names, but pick a meaningful real Chinese name for themselves instead.*